# Google deepmind q learning setup

Tags: command-line, terminal, neural-network, deep-learning, command-line-tool

Hi I'm trying to run the deepmind q learning software on my mac. I believe I have all the necessary libraries to run the network. I don't understand however to actually run the "run_cpu" or "run_gpu" command. Ive tried running it in terminal with the file followed by the game name breakout. I.e. "./run_gpu breakout". The github page with the code says that all you need to do is copy the rom from the roms folder but I'm not quite sure what that means/how to do it. The repository can be found here: https://github.com/kuz/DeepMind-Atari-Deep-Q-Learner

I'm sure I'm missing something really really simple here. Here's the terminal print out:

```
    Els-MacBook-Air:DeepMind-Atari-Deep-Q-Learner-master elcapitan$ ./run_gpu breakout 
    -framework alewrap -game_path /Users/elcapitan/Desktop/DeepMind-Atari-
Deep-Q-Learner-master/roms/ -name DQN3_0_1_breakout_FULL_Y -env breakout -
env_params useRGB=true -agent NeuralQLearner -agent_params 
lr=0.00025,ep=1,ep_end=0.1,ep_endt=replay_memory,discount=0.99,hist_len=4,learn_start=50000,replay_memory=1000000,update_freq=4,n_replay=1,network="co
nvnet_atari3",preproc="net_downsample_2x_full_y",state_dim=7056,minibatch_s
ize=32,rescale_r=1,ncols=1,bufferSize=512,valid_size=500,target_q=10000,cli
p_delta=1,min_reward=-1,max_reward=1 -steps 50000000 -eval_freq 250000 -
eval_steps 125000 -prog_freq 10000 -save_freq 125000 -actrep 4 -gpu 0 -
random_starts 30 -pool_frms type="max",size=2 -seed 1 -threads 4
    ./run_gpu: line 46: qlua: command not found
```

Sorry if this sounds uber dumb. Anyway I'd appreciate a solution if you have one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install qlua, try

```
sudo luarocks install qtlua
```